# void fun() virtual vs void(*fun)()

Tags: c++, virtual

Добрый день, сильно интересует, что из этого лучше использовать и почему.

```
class Parent {
public:

  Parent(void (*fun)()) {
    get = fun;
  }

  void(*get)();
};
```

и

```
class Parent {
public:

int i;

Parent(int i) {
    this->i = i;
}

    void get() virtual;
};


class Child1 : Parent {
public:
    void get() {
        cout << "Error#1";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Виртуальные методы вызываются через *таблицу виртуальных функций*. Она общая для всех объектов одного и того же класса, а потому существует в единственном экземпляре в секции константных данных. А объекты просто ссылаются на эту таблицу через неявно хранимое поле `vptr`.

   Поэтому виртуальные методы используют там, где одна и та же функция применяется во всех экземплярах класса без изменений.
2. Ну а члены-указатели хранятся непосредственно внутри объекта, из-за чего происходит дублирование. Как результат, у каждого объекта оказывается независимая копия.

   Поэтому указатели на функции используют, если каждый экземпляр одного и того же класса использует какой-то свой вариант функции, возможно, даже передаваемый извне.